# Change the order of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have the following claim to be verified.

[Claim]
Suppose

(1) $f_m$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ for each $m\in \mathbb N$;

(2) $x_n \to 0$ is a sequence of numbers;

(3) $\lim\inf_{m\to \infty} f_m (x_n) \ge 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Then, we have 
$$\lim\inf_{m\to \infty} f_m(0) \ge 0.$$

For this above claim, I have a preliminary proof here.

[Q.] Is this correct? If not, please give me a simple counter-example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is wrong. Consider the following counter-example:
$f_m(x) = (-1 + mx) I_{(-\infty, 1/m)}(x)$ at $x_n = 1/2n$.